# What is the syntax to define the border on table in Aspose.PDF XSLT

Tags: xslt, aspose, aspose.pdf

I am writing the XSLT transform for the Aspose.PDF, how do I add the border to the table?

Any links to Aspose xslt examples would be great (their documentation regarding the xslt is very poor).

I have tried to add the border using the Border tag, but it doesn't seem to be working, what I am missing?

```
<Table ColumnSpacing='120' ColumnWidths="100 100" BackgroundColor="#EAECEE">
    <Border Color="#000000" Left="1px" Right="1px" Top="1px" Bottom="1px"/>...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the following ways:

```
<Table ColumnWidths="100 100">
   <Border>
      <Bottom LineWidth="1" Color="#000000"/>
      <Top LineWidth="1" />
      <Right LineWidth="1" BorderStyle="None"/>
      <Left LineWidth="1" BorderStyle="None"/>
   </Border>
</Table>

<Table ColumnWidths="100 100">
   <Border>
      <All LineWidth="1" Color="#000000"/>
   </Border>
</Table>
```

Hope it helps. Otherwise, feel free to ask me.

**Note**: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.